# loop matched string in a text file

Tags: bash, loops

How can i loop by string "BUILD #" and only print the lines which has following string "http://" using bash script?
 or how can we have everything in between to strings "BUILD "
input.txt

```
BUILD #1
http://a
b
http://c

BUILD #2
http://d
http://c
http://g


BUILD #3
g
http://h
http://f
e
http://t
```

desired output

<sup>**Editor's note**: As evidenced by what answer was accepted, the question turned out *not* to be about producing *filtered* output, but about selectively *processing* lines in a manner that is aware of the enclosing *build context*,
 as implied by the respective preceding `BUILD #<n>` line.</sup>

```
BUILD #1 (loop)
http://a
http://c
add another loop to do something with http://

BUILD #2 (loop)
http://d
http://c
http://g
add another loop to do something with http://

BUILD #3 (loop)
http://h
http://f
http://t
add another loop to do something with http://
```

---

input.txt has list of Merge request.

```
BUILD #1
take the link (integrate)
take the link (integrate)
kick of a build (build command)
BUILD #2 
take the link (integrate)
take the link (integrate)
take the link (integrate)
kick of a build (build command)
and so on
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can loop it like this:

```
while read -r; do
   # if current line starts with BUILD then set a variable build with build #
   [[ $REPLY == BUILD* ]] && build="${REPLY#BUILD }" && continue

   # if current line starts with http:// then execute a command using build # & link
   [[ $REPLY == http://* ]] && printf "Build: %s -> Link: %s\n" "$build" "$REPLY"
done < input.txt

Build: #1 -> Link: http://a
Build: #1 -> Link: http://c
Build: #2 -> Link: http://d
Build: #2 -> Link: http://c
Build: #2 -> Link: http://g
Build: #3 -> Link: http://h
Build: #3 -> Link: http://f
Build: #3 -> Link: http://t
```

You can change `printf` to any other command you want.

Answer (score 1):

[anubhava's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43377482/45375) shows you how to iterate over the lines sequentially, recording the current build number as each build-specific block of lines is entered.

Here's a solution that processes the lines *build by build*, in *blocks* of lines, so you can apply build-level operations, if needed.

*All* blocks are processed in sequence, but it wouldn't be hard to adapt the solution to target a specific build by number only.

```
#!/bin/bash

buildNum= urls=() finalIteration=0
while IFS= read -r line || { finalIteration=1; true; }; do
   # A new build block is starting or EOF was reached.
  if [[ $line =~ ^'BUILD #'([0-9]+) || $finalIteration -eq 1 ]]; then
    if [[ $buildNum ]]; then # Process the previous block.
      echo "Processing build #$buildNum..."
      # Process all URLs.
      i=0
      for url in "${urls[@]}"; do
        echo "Url #$((++i)): $url"
      done
      # Add further per-build processing here...
    fi    
    (( finalIteration )) && break # Exit the loop, if EOF reached.
    # Save this block's build number.
    buildNum=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    urls=() # Reset the array of URLs.
  # Collect the lines of interest in array ${url[@]}, for later processing.
  elif [[ $line =~ ^http:// ]]; then
    urls+=( "$line" )
  fi
done < input.txt
```